# Scheduling a ZFS scrub on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cron, zfs

I have discovered that ZFS on Ubuntu 16.04 configures a scrub of all pools
the second Sunday of every month via `/etc/cron.d/zfsutils-linux`.

I would like to change this to once every three months.

Can I just edit /etc/cron.d/zfsutils-linux and change this

```
# Scrub the second Sunday of every month.
24 0 8-14 * * root [ $(date +\%w) -eq 0 ] && [ -x /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub ] && /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub
```

to this one?

```
# Scrub the first Sunday of of Mar,Jun,Sep, Dec
05 0 1-7 3,6,9,12 0  root [ $(date +\%w) -eq 0 ] && [ -x /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub ] && /usr/lib/zfs-linux/scrub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*         *       *               *                *
Minute    Hour    Day of Month    Month of Year    Day of Week
05        0       1-7             3,6,9,12         0
```

Yes, because you have told it to run on the fifth minute of midnight, if pithing the first seven days of the months March, June, September, or December, it is a Sunday.

The part with `$(date +\%w) -eq 0 && ...` converts the output of `date` into the numeric value of the day of the week and checks if it is `0`, or a Sunday, before running the scrub job.